# Multiple SQL Statement with Order By Using UNION ALL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to get latest Top 1 items from different tables and sort the result based on the date in desc and then select top 1 record based on Date

```
SELECT TOP 1 PublishDate, 'Article' FROM Articles ORDER BY PublishDate
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 PublishDate, 'News' FROM News ORDER BY NewsDate
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 CreateDate, 'Blog' FROM Blog ORDER BY BlogDate
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 PostDate, 'Videos' FROM Videos ORDER BY NewsDate
```

In result I should have 1 record with the latest based on latest publish date.

I tried to use `ORDER BY` in all statement in a stored procedure but it doesn't work as it throws an error. How can I get the desired result use this or CTE query.

I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Try to put parentheses around each query: `(select ...) union all (select ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try making another subselect:

```
select top 1 date, type from 
(SELECT 
   TOP 1  PublishDate as date, 'Article' as type 
   FROM Articles 
   ORDER BY  PublishDate 
 UNION ALL SELECT 
   TOP 1  PublishDate as date, 'News' as type 
   FROM News ORDER BY  NewsDate 
 UNION ALL SELECT TOP 1  CreateDate as date, 'Blog' as type 
   FROM Blog ORDER BY  BlogDate 
   UNION ALL SELECT TOP 1  PostDate as date, 'Videos' as type 
   FROM Videos ORDER BY  NewsDate) as unions 
order by date
```

Comment: It give error `No column name was specified for column 2 of 'unions'`

Comment: Glad to help you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select * from 
(SELECT TOP 1  PublishDate, 'Article'  as description FROM Articles 
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1  PublishDate, 'News' FROM News 
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1  CreateDate, 'Blog' FROM Blog 
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1  PostDate, 'Videos' FROM Videos) as a ORDER BY description
```